# Product Filter Query

Tags: php, mysql

We have implemented a shopping carts in which various filters like color,size etc there.

Currently we have used single table for products & their filters, So whenever need to fetch products we use query below mentioned:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (color='red' OR color='yellow') AND size=s
```

Now in our database 1500000 rows and 20 filters which creates around 90 columns in products table due to this product table is too heavy. So we have changed the database structure and create new table for managing product-filter relationship.

We are providing an [sql file](http://www.webassist.com/webassist/actions/do_download.php?file=101/314/162/wa_ecommerce_db-8072013.zip&from=/community/tutorials/view_tutorial.php) for sample of new database and we need to fetch products having color=red,yellow & size=s.

Query mentioned below is already used for finding products having red color or yellow display however if we use other option group (size), then we need query like this  (options.OptionName = 'red' OR options.OptionName = 'yellow') and options.OptionName = 's'  which result 0 rows as both option group values in different rows.

```
SELECT products.ProductID,options.* FROM Products
INNER JOIN productoptions on Products.ProductID = productoptions.ProductID
INNER JOIN options ON options.OptionID = productoptions.OptionID
WHERE options.OptionName = 'red' OR options.OptionName = 'yellow'
```

kindly suggest

Comment: What is your question?  Can you please edit the question and clarify what you are asking?

Comment: If you use Indian units of counting (lakh, crore) it's a kindness to westerners to also translate them into kilo / mega / giga units. Also, it's helpful when you post your table definitions.

Comment: Post your sql using pastebin (or here if short), I will not register in your site just to see the file

Answer (score 0):

You can filter subsets by properties (eg: color, size, ...) and make the intersection of these subsets:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    products
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            productoptions.ProductID,
            OptionName
        FROM
            productoptions
        INNER JOIN
            options
        ON
            productoptions.OptionID = options.OptionID
        WHERE
            options.OptionName = 'red' OR options.OptionName = 'blue'
    ) as OptGroup1
ON
    OptGroup1.ProductID = products.ProductID

INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            productoptions.ProductID,
            OptionName
        FROM
            productoptions
        INNER JOIN
            options
        ON
            productoptions.OptionID = options.OptionID
        WHERE
            options.OptionName = 'M'
    ) as OptGroup2
ON
    OptGroup2.ProductID = products.ProductID
```

I have another dirty solution, but it is not optimal: Concat product properties into one field after you can filter in it for example with **LIKE**:

```
SELECT 
    products.ProductId, 
    options.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('-',options.OptionGroupID, options.OptionName)) as properies
FROM 
    products
INNER JOIN 
    productoptions on products.ProductID = productoptions.ProductID
INNER JOIN 
    options ON options.OptionID = productoptions.OptionID
GROUP BY
    ProductId
HAVING 
    (properies LIKE '%1-red%' OR properies = '%1-yellow%') AND properies LIKE '%2-S%';
```

*PS: But I think the best solution is if you introduce a search server eg.: [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)*

Comment: Thanks a lot Attila for providing both solutions.

I have checked both solutions however as i mentioned we have 20 filters and atleast 5-6 filters works at a time. 
For first solution we need to join 5-6 times also when i run for 2 inner join it takes time to execute.
Second solution perfectly run and too fast. However as you mentioned  dirty solution, I have searched and found that it have maximum limit. Although we increase the limit.
So should we use second one
Kindly Suggest

Comment: Could you please provide me the query for GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('-',options.OptionGroupID, options.OptionName)) as properies only for selected filter like color or size

Comment: You can filter to selected options in WHERE clause, for example: [link](http://pastebin.com/srB3p7zT)

Comment: Hi Attila,
Thanks for your reply.
Actually i need result like if we want color then 
red(1)
blue(2)